# Equation environment definition

Tags: equations, environments, latex-base

Where is the full definition of the equation environment? I cannot find it in the `.cls` files. Is this in `latex.ltx`? Or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `texdoc source2e` it starts on p214. It's in [ltmath.dtx](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/base/ltmath.dtx).

Here it is:

```
\@definecounter{equation}
\def\equation{$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
\def\endequation{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
```

Comment: I'll try to mimic this piece of code to understand how it behaves. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can find it in `latex.ltx`. Seamus pointet you already to the source in  `ltmath.dtx` and noted the three lines.

If you use equations, you very probably use the amsmath package because that's very recommendable for writing math texts. This package redefines the `equation` environment! It even defines a starred environment `equation*`.

So, if you use amsmath, you can find the definition of the equation environment in `amsmath.sty`:

```
\renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

Even `\[ ... \]` is redefined to use this `equation*`. For more information regarding the used macros look at `amsmath.sty`. Or just at `latex.ltx`, if you decide to to without amsmath.

Comment: I find it strange to see portions of code in latex.ltx, other portions, in cls files and some other in sty files. Thanks

Comment: @pluton: Why not - some are standard (latex.ltx) and available everywhere, some are for use only with a certain class (.cls) - chapter commands would be meaningless in articles, some are provided by packages (.sty) and can be used with any class you like - optionally.